# Meteor handle.ready() in render() not triggering rerender of component

Tags: reactjs, meteor, collections

I have the following code in my render method:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
                {this.props.spatulaReady.ready() ? <p>{this.props.spatula.name}</p> : <p>loading spatula</p>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Which according to my understanding, checks if the subscriptionhandle is ready (data is there) and displays it. If no data is available, it should display a simple loading message. However, when I first load the page this snippet is on, it get's stuck on the loading part. On a page reload the data (usually) displays fine.

If I check the spatulaReady.ready() when the page first loads and while the display is stuck on 'loading spatula', and the data that should be there, the handle reports as ready and the data is there like it is supposed to be. If I refresh the page it all displays fine as well. The problem is, this way of checking for data and rendering if it has arrived has worked fine for me in the past. Is it because the render method is not reactive? Because handle.ready() should be reactive.

What makes it even weirder is that it sometimes DOES correctly display the data on page load, seemingly at random.

CreateContainer code:

```
export default createContainer(props => {
    return {
        user: Meteor.user(),
        spatulaReady: Meteor.subscribe('spatula.byId', props.deviceId),
        spatula: SpatulaCollection.findOne()
    }
}, SpatulaConfig)
```

Publication code:

```
Meteor.publish('spatula.byId', function(deviceId) {
    const ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Error while obtaining spatula by id'

    if (!this.userId) //Check for login
        throw new Meteor.Error('Subscription denied!')
    const spatula = SpatulaCollection.findOne({_id: deviceId})
    if(!spatula) //No spatula by this id
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, ERROR_MESSAGE)
    if(spatula.ownedBy != this.userId) //Spatula does not belong to this user
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, ERROR_MESSAGE)

    return SpatulaCollection.find({_id: deviceId})

})
```

I know I'm missing a piece of the puzzle here, but I've been unsuccessful at finding it. If you don't know the solution to my specific problem, pointing me in the right direction with another way of waiting for the data to arrive before displaying it is also greatly appreciated.

EDIT: After doing some trial-and-error and reading various other posts somewhat related to my project, I figured out the solution:

```
export default createContainer(props => {
    const sHandle= Meteor.subscribe('spatula.byId', props.deviceId)
    return {
        user: Meteor.user(),
        spatulaReady: sHandle.ready(),
        spatula: SpatulaCollection.findOne()
    }
}, SpatulaConfig)
```

It still makes no sense to me that moving the ready() call to create container fixed all my problems though.

Comment: Try placing the `.ready()` call in the container. I believe that it is related to reactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you figured out, moving the `.ready()` call to `createContainer` fixes the problem. This is because Meteor reactivity only works when you call a *reactive data source* (a reactive function), such as `collection.find()` or `subscriptionHandle.ready()` within a *reactive context*, such as `Tracker.autorun` or `createContainer`. Functions within the React component, including `render`, are **not** reactive contexts from Meteor's perspective.

Note that React and Meteor reactivity are two different things. React's reactivity works simply so that whenever a component's `props` or `state` change, it's `render` function is re-run. It does not understand anything about Meteor's reactive data sources. Since `createContainer` (that is re-run by *Meteor* reactivity when reactive data sources in it change) simply passes props to the underlying component, the component is re-rendered by React when the props given from `createContainer` change.